# Free Loopback database connectors

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have been doing research on selected framework for my next restful api project. Loopback seems like the best option. But in order to use `mssql connector`, I have to pay Strongloop an annual fee. Is there anyway I can use some other connector for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of Enterprise Connectors in a Loopback project need you to pay a subscription fee to Strongloop. These include `Oracle`, `SQL Server`, `SOAP`, `ATG` and `Sharepoint`.

Now if you don't want to pay Strongloop the subscription fee, you need to switch to other database like `MySQL`, `MongoDB`, `PostgreSQL` etc and use their database connectors instead. Basically open-source data connectors and open-source service connectors are free to use.

But if you still insist on using SQL Server, then 'No' there is no other alternative `mssql connector` as communicated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/8PD5lQeWWLQ).